# How to grab data from a PLIST with JS based on Key name?

Tags: javascript, xml

So I have a plist file with many `<key>name</key>` that render to `<string>value</string>`

So I’m wondering if there is a way to render this data using JS create nodes. Creating a node based on the key name and it’s value, and then giving each key a variable name

I’m doing this as I’m trying to make a tool that will grab an entire `<dict>` (dictionary) from the code and separating each one based on its key name,

I’m basically trying to make a PLIST merger that will transfer an entire dictionary to another PLIST file

It’s annoyingly hard and slow to do it manually

Sorry if the typing had, I only have a phone and I’m learning English still

Comment: this sounds interesting, +1. I too use property lists in my iOS projects :)

And yes, I shall admit, Transferring a dictionary to another property list, especially manually on an iDevice, can be a pain.

Comment: O sorry, I always forget to wrap code. thanks for editing and reminding me